# How to Calculate Integral $\int_0^1 \theta^{-1} (1 - \theta)^{n-1} d\theta$

Tags: integration

Can anyone give any hints on how to calculate

$$\begin{equation}
   \int_0^1 \theta^{-1} (1-\theta)^{n-1} d\theta
\end{equation}$$
?

Thank You so much!

Comment: The integral is divergent at the endpoint $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral as currently stated is divergent. If you meant to have different bounds, this is how you can express the indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{(1-x)^{n-1}}{x} dx \\ =\int \frac 1x \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {{n-1}\choose k} (-x)^k dx \\ =\int\frac{dx}{x} +\int\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {{n-1}\choose k}(-1)^k x^k dx \\ =\ln x +\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}
$$ See how evaluating the term at $x=0$ paired with the minus sign would give $-\ln(0) =\infty$?